# Building project with Gradle results in NoSuchFileException as hidden folder is missing from declared plugin 'org.siouan.frontend-jdk17'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to use `frontend-gradle-plugin` to package up my React frontend project to use with Springboot. I cannot seem to get the dependency to download from the repo, and it's causing a missing file exception due to it not existing.

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    // For JDK 17+
    id 'org.siouan.frontend-jdk17' version '7.0.0'
}

group = 'uk.co.'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf
//  implementation group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '2.0.5'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Exception;

```
$ gradle build

> Configure project :
in build.gradle
In frontend build.gradle code block

> Task :assembleFrontend FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':assembleFrontend'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':assembleFrontend' property 'executableType'.
   > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/****/IdeaProjects/StarTrekSpellingWebApp/star-trek-spelling-game/.frontend-gradle-plugin/resolvePackageManager/package-manager-specification.txt

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
2

actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

I've tried using a `buildscript` block in `build.gradle` but every repository I use could not be found

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
            name 'Gradle'
        }

//      maven {
//          url 'https://maven.google.com/'
//          name 'Google'
//      }
//      google()
//      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // For JDK 17+
//      classpath 'org.siouan:frontend-gradle-plugin-jdk17:7.0.0'
        // For JDK 11+
        classpath 'org.siouan:frontend-gradle-plugin-jdk11:7.0.0'
    }
}
```

Exception;

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'star-trek-spelling-game'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.siouan:frontend-gradle-plugin-jdk11:7.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/siouan/frontend-gradle-plugin-jdk11/7.0.0/frontend-gradle-plugin-jdk11-7.0.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem given the `build.gradle` file you provided. Moreover, I did not manage to have task `assembleFrontend` be executed with command `gradle build` since the plugin has not been configured in the build script (`frontend` block is missing and `assembleScript` property is not defined).

Can you provide a minimal project to help reproducing the problem?